# Tricky Python Pandas merge, concat, or join

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2x pd.DataFrames:

```
In [2]  df1 = pd.DataFrame([[105,22555,'front office'],[106,22666,'back office'],[107,22777,'kitchen']],
                  columns=['office_id','contract','info'])
        print(df1)

Out[2]
   office_id  contract          info
0        105     22555  front office
1        106     22666   back office
2        107     22777       kitchen


In [3]  df2 = pd.DataFrame([[22555,np.NaN,'paper clips'],[22556,105,'printing paper'],
                           [22666,np.NaN,'chairs'],[22777,np.NaN,'crackers'],[22778,107,'cheese']],
                          columns=['contract','office_id','description'])
        print(df2)

Out[3]
   contract  office_id     description
0     22555        NaN     paper clips
1     22556      105.0  printing paper
2     22666        NaN          chairs
3     22777        NaN        crackers
4     22778      107.0          cheese
```

I need to concat, merge, or join on `contract` or `office_id` to create a pd.DataFrame like this:

```
   office_id  contract     description          info
0        105     22555     paper clips  front office
1        105     22556  printing paper  front office
2        106     22666          chairs   back office
3        107     22777        crackers       kitchen
4        107     22778          cheese       kitchen
```

The recommendations should not included any loops as this will need to be applied to a large data-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
columns=['office_id','contract','description','info']
df = df1.merge(df2,on='contract',how='outer')
df['office_id_x']=df['office_id_x'].fillna(df['office_id_y'])
df = df.merge(df1[['office_id','info']],left_on='office_id_x',right_on='office_id')
df=df[['office_id_x','contract','description','info_y']]
df.columns=columns
df['office_id'] = df['office_id'].astype(int)
print(df)
   office_id  contract     description          info
0        105     22555     paper clips  front office
1        105     22556  printing paper  front office
2        106     22666          chairs   back office
3        107     22777        crackers       kitchen
4        107     22778          cheese       kitchen
```